# Logs are not displaying inside a subscribe method in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote a service like this,

```
getcategorys(){
   console.log("in category service");
    return this.http.get(this.url+"getAll")
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

and called it from a component like this,

```
this.CategoryService.getcategorys()
  .subscribe(categories => 
    {

    this.categories = categories;
    console.log("adasd",this.categories.length); 

    for(this.category in this.categories) {

    console.log("List of category :",this.category.id);

//call one more subscribe here.


  },
  error => {
    console.log("Error Message:", error);
  }
);
```

but the log statements are never printing. The actual work is i need to get the ID field from each category object and then call another service to get the respect services.

can someone help its not working ?

Comment: is `in category service` printed ?

Comment: yes thats getting printed but not in subscribe log

Comment: you can try using the map function inside your subscribe method

Comment: If you're using HttpClient (not http) you needn't use map res=>res.json. Be sure that you received data and the url is correct. The code looks like be ok